# Restore previous session's attribute

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web, session-timeout

Suppose, a use login with username="ABC",

Some data is set in the session as follows:
session.setAttribute("mydata", mydata);

If the current session expires, the user is redirected with login page.

And now, if the user again login with same username ("ABC"),

Can we retrieve the previous session's attribute so that the user can continue his work?

Please suggest me the possible solution to retrieve the data of previous session.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible . However, you can always create a semaphore where your app can check against it whenever the user logs in and invalidate the session if there's already an existing user session running.

This semaphore could be as simple as a Java static variable if you are running in a non-clustered environment, or a better approach is to set the flag in a database table especially if you are running in the clustered environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, when the session expires everything it contains is dead. This is controlled by the container.

Answer (score 0):

You could save session attributes to database beofre they expire, then add them back to the new session when user logs in again.